# How to upload my webpage files into wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am wanting to add a Webpage (1 page) into my domain name that has WordPress installed. I want to view my page in *mywordpressite.com/page1*. I already have my html, css, and JavaScript files ready I just need to know HOW I can view the page in WordPress. Information like where to add the files would be great.

Thank you,

Abraham G.

Comment: WordPress is a Content Management System that allows you to create pages under the "Pages" section.  Otherwise, you would not put your own static HTML files _into_ WordPress... they'd be _outside_ of WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could actually add it to wordpress theme:

1) Converte your index.php into a page template for the theme in wordpress (more information in: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates )

2) Upload the files to your theme directory.

3) Create a page named "launch" in your wordpress administration. Select the template page your just created, save and its done ;)